# Simple example of CALayer usage -- perhaps in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextfield, calayer

I have an requirement to implement a custom keyboard for a Cocoa Touch data entry screen containing multiple UITextFields. I've built the keyboard, and everything is working except now I need to figure out how to implement a blinking cursor. (When you disable the UITextField's built-in keyboard, you lose the cursor as well). In googling around, I've seen a few mentions of using CALayer animation to do this. However, I have not yet found a simple example of how I might implement this. Since UITextField inherits from UIView, I was hoping I could use the text fields view as the host layer. The animation part of the blink is not what is worrying me, it is just setting this up properly. Any advice, or pointers to other sites containing a simple tutorial? (everything I've found has been oriented toward multi-layers and games, and not built on top of a basic view/textfield).

Comment: Update: I've found some useful info by RTFM, looking in the Core Animation Programming Guide, "Layer Tree Hierarchy" section.
I'd still appreciate any advice you might have though.

Comment: It occurs to me that there's probably a way that you could still have the normal keyboard behaviour but show your custom keyboard over the top of it. That way you wouldn't have to implement a caret and keep track of input position and deal with dragging of the caret etc. Not sure how you go about it though, hence this being a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have had to basically cycle a animation of a black CAlayer's opacity property from 0 to 1 repeatedly, but now you have custom input views https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Text/Text.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH8